# How to execute shell command with JSON from java

Tags: java, process, processbuilder

I'm not able to execute a command with JSON in Java process or `ProcessBuilder`,
here I included a model command I execute,

```
ArrayList<String> outPut = new ArrayList<String>();
String sp = "test -n test -p '{\"test\": {\"test\": {\"test\": {\"test\": {\"test\": \"test\"}}}}}'";
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(sp);
System.out.println(sp);
BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

String s = null;

while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
    outPut.add(s);
}

System.out.println(outPut);
```

Comment: in cmd, this command will work but not through java code

Comment: probably because `Runtime` does not use `'` or `"` to not separate arguments, that is, it divides the arguments just by space character (`StringTokenizer`). Try with [`exec(String[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String%5B%5D)) where you do the correct separation of arguments

Comment: Is `test` the executable to be run? If yes, what do the two consecutive calls do when executed manually via cmd?

Comment: @deHaar iam not runnging this camand but it is like this formate     ,              String sp = "test -n dev test1 -p '{\"test3\": {\"test4\": {\"test5\": {\"test6\": {\"test7\": \"test8\"}}}}}'";      , it will working fine direct cmd

Comment: OK, then put all the commands into a `List<String>`, the executable path first, and start a `ProcessBuilder` with that...

Comment: @deHaar I also checked with ProcedssBuilder with list parameter, but it will not work

Comment: How have you checked that? Can you show it? Can you show us an error message or describe what's not working as desired?

Comment: @SunilDabburi   Runtime.getRuntime().exec(sp) this line is enough for executing the command I check with the normal command it will work, JSON including time only the issue coming

Comment: @deHaar there is no error message. printing empty array. if it was working the array will print the cmd response

Comment: What does `process.exitValue()` return? `0`?

Comment: is `test` a program (executable), a shell alias, a shell script, ... or what???

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `Runtime.exec(String)` uses the `StringTokenizer` to split the argument and then call `Runtime.exec(String[])`.
The `StringTokenizer` is not able to split that argument *correctly* - it does not consider single quotes `'`. It ends up calling test with something like (one argument per line):

> ```
> -n
> test
> -p
> '{test:
> {test:
> {test:
> {test:
> {test:
> test}}}}}'
> ```

Solution as already commented: use `Runtime.exec(String[])`, e.g.:

```java
String[] cmd = { 
  "test", 
  "-n", 
  "test", 
  "-p", 
  "{\"test\": {\"test\": {\"test\": {\"test\": {\"test\": \"test\"}}}}}"
};
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

---

My test *program*:

```java
import java.io.*;

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try (Writer wr = new FileWriter("args.txt")) {
            for (String arg : args)
                wr.write(arg + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

<sup>very simple, done without using any IDE, sorry</sup>

I had to call java first, so my `cmd` is changed to `cmd = { "java", "test", "-n", ...`

Comment: I test with this formate. but it will not working :-(

Comment: works for me, but I am using my `test`, not sure what yours is.